# JWT Claims lost when running App Service in Azure

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, jwt

Recently implemented Asp.net core 2.0 WEB Api. Works smashingly on my local dev environment. HOWEVER ... when i deploy to AZURE i find that my JWT Access Token does NOT contain the Issuer and Audience claims and therefore i get the 401 Unauthorized with : Bearer error="invalid_token", error_description="The audience is invalid". The JWT generated on my local machine has : (courtesy of jwt.io)

```
{
"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/...": "Rory@gspin.com",
"sub": "Rory@gspin.com",
"given_name": "Rory",
"family_name": "McGilroy",
"email": "Rory@gspin.com",
"jti": "3875f83d-eb93-4d45-8507-795a0cb7e3e4",
"iat": 1533506381,
"rol": "api_access",
"id": "420990b2-4747-4c3c-ae0f-ccbbc4dfe521",
"nbf": 1533506381,
"exp": 1533513581,
"iss": "gspin.com",
"aud": "https://www.gspin.com"
}
```

But after deploying same application to AZURE APP Service my Access Token contains the following:

```
{
"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/...": "billyttom@fido.com",
"sub": "billyttom@fido.com",
"given_name": "billy mark tom",
"family_name": "last",
"email": "billyttom@fido.com",
"jti": "0d34a03f-31ae-45aa-9ace-004d5916b430",
"iat": 1533498384,
"rol": "api_access",
"id": "5485d641-974b-4f60-ade6-35c048503701",
"nbf": 1533498383,
"exp": 1533505583
}
```

Missing **iss** and **aud**???

Any idea why these are being dropped when deployed to azure when they are defined and present in Token generated on local machine/Visual Studio env?

```
My Code is :         public async Task<string> GenerateEncodedToken(string 
userName, ClaimsIdentity identity, UserManager<GSIdentityUser> _userManager)
    {
        var user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(userName);
        var userClaims = await _userManager.GetClaimsAsync(user);
        var claims = new[]
     {
             new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, userName),
             new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub, userName),
             new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.GivenName, user.FirstName),
             new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.FamilyName, user.LastName),
             new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Email, user.Email), /// same as username
             new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, await _jwtOptions.JtiGenerator()), // the uniqueness claim is a GUID
             new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Iat, ToUnixEpochDate(_jwtOptions.IssuedAt).ToString(), ClaimValueTypes.Integer64),
             identity.FindFirst(Helpers.Constants.Strings.JwtClaimIdentifiers.Rol),
             identity.FindFirst(Helpers.Constants.Strings.JwtClaimIdentifiers.Id)
         };
        // Create the JWT security token and encode it.
        var jwt = new JwtSecurityToken(
            issuer: _jwtOptions.Issuer,
            audience: _jwtOptions.Audience,
            claims: claims,
            notBefore: _jwtOptions.NotBefore,
            expires: _jwtOptions.Expiration,
            signingCredentials: _jwtOptions.SigningCredentials);

        var encodedJwt = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(jwt);
        return encodedJwt;
    }
    public ClaimsIdentity GenerateClaimsIdentity(string userName, string id)
    {
        return new ClaimsIdentity(new GenericIdentity(userName, "Token"), new[]
        {
            new Claim(Helpers.Constants.Strings.JwtClaimIdentifiers.Id, id),
            new Claim(Helpers.Constants.Strings.JwtClaimIdentifiers.Rol, Helpers.Constants.Strings.JwtClaims.ApiAccess)
        });
    }


Also in ConfigureServices i have :            
     services.Configure<JwtIssuerOptions>(options =>
            {
                options.Issuer = Configuration["JwtIssuerOptions:Issuer"]; 
                options.Audience=Configuration["JwtIssuerOptions:Audience"];
                options.SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(_signingKey, 
     SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);
            });
```

Comment: There must be a difference in the configuration of your authentication in Startup when deployed on Azure.

Comment: So you have a token generating endpoint? Could you show the code?

Comment: My Token Generation code is below : (see FullStackMark tutorial which is what i implemented - https://fullstackmark.com/post/13/jwt-authentication-with-aspnet-core-2-web-api-angular-5-net-core-identity-and-facebook-login)

Comment: Can you observe the values of `Configuration` object? Can you show how you build the `Configuration`? Which data sources you use to build `Configuration`? Can you show appsettings.json (or similar)?